# Block public access on S3, accessible from Cloudfront?

Tags: security, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I just received an email informing that my S3 buckets are publicly accessible, which is fine because I am hosting files there.

At the same time, I have Cloudfront serving the files stored in S3.

Thinking of a more secure configuration, a doubt arose: if I disable public access in S3, will the files still be served properly by Cloudfront?

Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your files are in an S3 bucket that is not configured as **Website Endpoint** then you should just make the S3 bucket private and let CloudFront serve the requests.

For this, you would want to setup **Origin Access Identity**. This allows you to keep your bucket private and only allow access through CloudFront.

Documentation: [Restricting Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Comment: Origin access identity is now considered a legacy solution. The official AWS documentation now recommends that Origin Access Control is used instead:

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website#

Comment: This particular video tutorial also does an excellent job of explaining how to set up an S3 website with CloudFront using Origin Access Control instead of a publicly accessible S3 static website bucket configuration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEIuuVKIy8U

Answer (score 1):

At creation time, you would tick the "Block Public Access" checkbox.

Then you will configure Origin Access Identity through CloudFront.